# how to implement multiple pagination in single page | laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

I have a situation where i want to implement multiple pagination in single page using laravel paginate() function.

code in Controller file.

```
$products=Product::paginate(10);
$users=Users::paginate(10);
return view('index',['products' => $products, 'users' => $users ]);
```

code in my view blade file.

```
{{    $products->links();  }}
{{    $users->links();  }}
```

Now when I click on user pagination than the product also show from current page only..

I am using laravel 5.7 can someone tell me how can I use multiple paginations in a single page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its because by default pagination url with `page`

To Change just pass few extra parametes to `paginate` method

**FROM**

```
$products=Product::paginate(10);
$users=Users::paginate(10);
return view('index',['products' => $products, 'users' => $users ]);
```

**TO**

```
$products=Product::paginate(20,['*'],'productPagination');
$users=Users::paginate(20,['*'],'userPagination');
return view('index',['products' => $products, 'users' => $users ]);
```

And here is the Pagination function

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/dfa006b884e4ca2952eeab1af7ecd151c0220db7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L742

Hope its helps